# What does equilibrium probability density mean in statistical mechanics?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I know that according to the book [Theory of Simple Liquids](https://www.elsevier.com/books/theory-of-simple-liquids/hansen/978-0-12-387032-2) by Hansen & McDonald:

> "The distribution of phase points of systems of the ensemble is described by a phase space probability density $f^{[N]}(\textbf{r}^N, \textbf{p}^N; t)$"

And,

> "The quantity $f^{[N]}d\textbf{r}^N d\textbf{p}^N$ is the probability that at time $t$ the physical system is in a microscopic state represented by a phase point lying in the infinitesimal, 6N -dimensional phasespace element $d\textbf{r}^N d\textbf{p}^N$"

But for a system in thermodynamical equilibrium the book says:

> "The phase space probability density of a system in thermodynamic
> equilibrium is a function of the time-varying coordinates and momenta, but
> is independent of t at each point in phase space. We shall use the symbol
> $f_0^{[N]}(\textbf{r}^N, \textbf{p}^N)$ to denote the equilibrium probability density."

My question is: What does this equilibrium probability density $f_0^{[N]}$ mean? I'm guessing it is a measure of the probability of a system being in a particular state at equilibrium. I'm trying to find a source I can cite, preferably a book, that proves this statement.

Answer (score 1):

$f^{[N]}(\mathbf{r}^N, \mathbf{p}^N; t)$ assigns a probability (technically a probability density) to each microstate. A microstate is defined by a list of the positions and momenta of each of the $N$ particles of the system. This distribution, in general, depends on time.

When the distribution does not depend on time, then it is a stationary distribution. This may also be an equilibrium distribution in the sense that the system will approach $f^{[N]}$ at large enough times.

In thermal equilbrium, you should find $f^{[N]}(\mathbf{r}^N, \mathbf{p}^N) \propto e^{-E(\mathbf{r}^N, \mathbf{p}^N)/kT}$, ie, the Boltzmann distribution.

Comment: Then is it correct to say that in thermodynamic equilibrium $f^[N]$ is the probability of a system being in a particular state (which is in equilibrium)? And if so, What book would you use to validate this?

Comment: @felipe I wouldn't phrase it like that. I would say the equilibrium distribution $f^{[N]}(\mathbf{r}^N, \mathbf{p}^N)$ is a time-independent probability distribution over the system's microstates, which are labeled by $\{\mathbf{r}^N, \mathbf{p}^N\}$.

Comment: The phrase "the state of the system" is ambiguous, since it could refer to the *microstate* of the system, or the *macrostate* of the system, and possibly other meanings. Without other context, I would tend to think "the state of the system" means a *macrostate*, so I would make statements like "the state of the system is in equilibrium if its distribution of microstates (given by $f^{[N]})$ is an equilibrium distribution." But again, the phrase "state of the system" can be ambiguous, so best to be more precise if you can.